# PostgreSQL 9.3: Update tables contained in a view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a view which contains 3 tables. I want to update the each tables contained in the view.

**Tables**:

Table 1: test1

```
create table test1
(
id int,
name text,
city text
);

insert into test1 values(1,'Abc','xyz');
```

Table 2: test2

```
create table test2
(
id int,
name text,
city text
);

insert into test2 values(1,'bc','xz');
```

Table 3: test3

```
create table test3
(
id int,
name text,
city text
);

insert into test3 values(1,'Ac','yz');
```

**View**:

```
create view myview as select * from test1 union all select * from test2 union all select * from test3;
```

**Note**: I have a situation where I need to update the all `tables` city at once. So I have written a function
which does the update for a single table.

```
create or replace function updatefun(tablename text)

returns void as

$body$

Declare
    query varchar;
Begin
    query := 'Update '||tablename||'
         set city = ''XXX''';

    raise info '%',query;

    execute query;
end;

$body$

Language plpgsql;
```

I have another table which contains the `ViewId` and `ViewName`.

```
create table viewdetails
(
ViewId int,
ViewName text
);

insert into viewdetails values(101,'myview');
```

Now I want to write another function to get all tables from the view and want to call the
function `updatefun` from this function to update all tables.

## My try:

```
create or replace function fun1(vId int)

returns void as

$body$

declare
    query varchar;
    rec1 record;
    rec2 record;
    
begin
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table1;

    create temp table temp_table1(viewNames text);

    query := 'insert into temp_table1 select ViewName from ViewDetails where ViewId = '|| vId ||'';

    execute query;

    for rec1 in select ViewNames from temp_table1 loop

        for rec2 in SELECT Table_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE  WHERE View_Name = 'rec1' loop

            select updatefun('rec2');

        end loop;

    end loop;
end;

$body$

language plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:

```
select fun1(101);
```

**Checking view**:

```
select * from myview;
```

Not getting why it is not getting updated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

<strike>`select updatefun('rec2');`</strike>

You want

```
perform updatefun(rec2);
```

without any quotes around `rec2` otherwise it's interpreted as a literal, not the name of a variable.

Additionally `rec2` should be of type `TEXT`, not `RECORD`.

Comment: Exactly. And one more change was `rec1` is also have to be a type of `TEXT` and not to enclose it the single quote.